# Checking if a variable has changed and than update shape Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, macos

Is there a way for swift code to check if this variable changes and than change the shape of an object?

```
var Shape = 0.4
let a = (self.size.width + self.size.height) * Shape
```

Comment: You should look into property observers. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/8/5/property-observers-didset

Comment: The Swift convention is to use `lowerCamelCase` for value identifiers. Also, isn't it strange that a thing called "shape" is ... not a shape? It's a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using property observers you can achieve what you are looking for. `didSet` will be called after varibale value changed.

```
var variable1 = 0 {
    didSet {
        onValueChange()
    }
}
    
func onValueChange() {
    print("Change \(variable1)")
}
```